# Something is wrong with taking the average of my array with user inputs

Tags: java, arrays, loops

1.So I'm messing up the average, when the program is cut short with a zero it gives me the wrong average. Any help would be appreciated, I think i need to divide the sum by the number of inputs entered but I've tried for hours and can't figure it out.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
public class Extremes {

public static void main(String[] Args){

    try(Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)){
        int array[] = new int[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter up to ten integers, entering a zero will stop allowing further inputs. ");
            int next = scan.nextInt();
            if (next == 0){
                break;}

            array[i] = next; }



        int max = getMax(array);
        System.out.println("Max value is " + max);  

        int min = getMin(array);
        System.out.println("Min value is " + min);
/*Alright so here is where I'm messing up and I think it's because of me
Dividing the sum by the average.length instead of by the amount of user    inputs 
entered, because the program only messes up when i use a zero instead of    entering all 10 intergers.
*/      
            double sum = 0;
            for(int i=1; i < array.length; i++)
                sum = sum + array[i];
            double average = sum/array.length;
            DecimalFormat fmtAverage = new DecimalFormat("0.####");
            System.out.println("The Average is " + fmtAverage.format(average));
        System.out.println("The Average is " + average);
    }





}

public static int getMax(int[] inputArray){
        int maxValue = inputArray[0];
        for(int i=0; i < inputArray.length;i++){
            if(inputArray[i] > maxValue){

            maxValue = inputArray[i];
            }

        }

    return maxValue;
}

public static int getMin(int[] inputArray){
    int minValue = inputArray[0];
    for(int i=0; i < inputArray.length;i++){
        if(inputArray[i] < minValue){

            minValue = inputArray[i];
        }

    }

return minValue;
}
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Java arrays indexes are zero-based,

Comment: `array.length` will always be 10... You need to count the no of inputs you actually get and use it to calculate the avg...

Comment: The program accepts up to 10 user inputs but if a zero is entered it stops, when the program is run with a zero entered, the average turns out to be wrong.

Comment: Yeah @codebender I keep trying to do that in many different ways and I'm not getting it right, just a little guidance on this would be helpful

Comment: When you cut short the data entry, you don't keep note how many numbers have been inputted. So you're running through the whole array when you haven't entered data into the whole array.

Comment: Is an `ArrayList<Integer>` out of the question. Then you won't have to worry about them not filling it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a counter.

```
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Enter up to ten integers, entering a zero will stop allowing further inputs. ");
    int next = scan.nextInt();
    if (next == 0){
        break;
    }
    counter++;
    array[i] = next; 
}

// So after that, you can use it as divider
double average = counter == 0 ? 0 : sum/counter;
```

Comment: Well it can be entered say 5,6,7,8,0 and then takes the average of that, I need to be able t divide by the user inputs entered, or have the array not be 10 integers if a zero is entered before 10 integers are entered

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't check you were initializing the array from the start as a 10-position array, so divider always going to be 10. I'd use a counter, my answer was updated.

Comment: And follow the @rjt suggestion, change the 1 by the 0 in the for.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was trying to do that but i was putting the counter variable inside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the following line

```
for(int i=1; i < array.length; i++)
```

With

```
for(int i=0; i < array.length; i++)
```

Comment: Now i just get the average is 10 no matter what